# Getting issue while using ui automator viewer in android for testing app

Tags: android, android-testing, android-uiautomator

Getting issue while using uiAutomator Viewer in android. In my app, first screen is login screen containing email edit text, checkbox for remembering credentials, password edit text and login button. When click on login button, function containing json response calls, after successfull json response of first function i call another json function, and on second json function response, third json function then fire intent.

But what is happening here it reaches on function, but do not call function or we can say didn't enter in the fucntion. For help you can see my code of LoginScreenActivity. I have tried by increasing time in also, but not getting why it behaves like this. Please help me

**LoginScreenActivity.java**

```
public void userLogin(String email,String password){
getFirstData();
}
public void getFirstData(){
code for json response
getSecondData();
}
public void getSecondData(){
code for json response
getThirdData();
}
public void getThirdData(){
code for json response
intent fire 
}
```

**LoginScreenActivityTest.java**

```
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
        loginScre = new LoginScreenActivity();
        mInstrumentation = getInstrumentation();
    }

    @Test
    public void getIntValue() throws Exception {
        device = UiDevice.getInstance(getInstrumentation());
        device.pressHome();
        device.wait(Until.hasObject(By.desc("Apps")), 3000);
        // device.wait(Until.hasObject(By.desc("Apps")), 3000);
        UiObject2 appsButton = device.findObject(By.desc("Apps"));
        appsButton.click();
        device.wait(Until.hasObject(By.desc("MyProject")), 3000);
        UiObject2 calculatorApp = device.findObject(By.text("MyProject"));
        calculatorApp.click();
        // UiObject editText = new UiObject(new UiSelector().className("android.widget.EditText").instance(1));
        UiObject editText = new UiObject(new UiSelector().resourceId("com.example.myproject:id/et_username"));
        editText.setText("abc@gmail.com");
        String emainEnter = editText.getText().toString();
        UiObject psswrd = new UiObject(new UiSelector().resourceId("com.example.myproject:id/et_password"));
        psswrd.click();
        psswrd.setText("abc123$");
        UiObject remember_me = new UiObject(new UiSelector().resourceId("com.example.myproject:id/remember_me"));
        if (!remember_me.isSelected()) {
            remember_me.click();
        }

        device.wait(Until.hasObject(By.text("Login")), 999000);
        UiObject2 buttonlogin = device.findObject(By.text("Login"));
        buttonlogin.click();
```

In this line `device.wait(Until.hasObject(By.text("Login")), 999000);` I have tried by changing the time also. But not able to find any solution. Please help me

Comment: Please bring your java code here...

Comment: Please check the code,i have edited with java file of testing